# Which is grammatically correct: 'update on' or 'update about' my status?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which one is correct?

> I will update you **on** my status.

or

> I will update you **about** my status.

Comment: Sorry @Matha, I was rash and wrong, hence I deleted my answer.

Comment: I think most people would say "..regarding my status"

Answer (score 6):

They are both grammatically correct. However, it is much more common to see "update on" rather than "update about". I would also say they mean slightly different things:

> I will update you on my status.

Means "I will tell you what my status is." It is very clear and definite.

> I will update you about my status.

Means something like "I will describe my status to you." The word *about* evolved from the figurative use of a word meaning *around*. This can still be seen by uses of *about* that mean *approximately* (e.g. "It's about a mile"), and there are even still uses that mean *physically around* (e.g. "Rotated about an axis"). Speaking "about" something implies that you are mentioning the qualities of the thing and discussing related subjects, not simply saying *what the thing is*.